# New in Java (Map and Set)

Tags: java

Can Any help me and Check my answer

**(a)** Declare a private instance variable (Attribute) called HouseMap which should hold an unsorted map with integer keys and string values.

```
Private Map< Integer, String> HouseMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

**(b)** Write a zero-argument constructor of HouseCatalogue that initializes HouseMap to an empty map.

```
houseMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

**(c)** Write an instance method called addHouse() for the HouseCatalogue class that takes no arguments, and returns no value. This method should simply enter the four entries shown above into the HouseMap.

```
Public void addHouse()
{
    HouseMap.put(101," adison Sas") ;
    HouseMap.put(103," FourSeasons") ;
    HouseMap.put(105," Hayat Regency "); 
    HouseMap.put(107," Concord al-Salam ") ;
}
```

**(d)** Write an instance method called printHouse() for the HouseCatalogue class that takes an integer argument, and return a string value. This method should print the value (House name) of the area code that is equal to integer argument and return it. Otherwise it will return null.

```
Public string printHouse( int area)
{
    for(Integer eachcode : HouseMap.keySet()) 
    { 
        if ( HouseMap.keySet()== area)
        {
            System.out.println("House name is"+ HouseMap.get(eachcode));
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void printHouse( int area)
{ 
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : houseMap.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(area)) 
        {
            System.out.println("House name is"+ entry.getValue());   
            //return entry.getValue();  //  return it      
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, since this is a community edited Q&A list, you should ask a question that can be answered. How would you answer the question 'New in Java (Map and Set)'? :)

Answer (score 3):

**(a)** Lower case letter for `private` and no `new HashMap()` needed when declaring. Normally when useing java convensions you use camelcase when declaring your variasbles (`houseMap`) but it's fine.

```
private Map<Integer, String> HouseMap;
```

**(b)** You have declared your variable with `HouseMap` not `houseMap` (see (a) camelcase) so initializing it needs the same variable:

```
HouseMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

**(c)** Seems fine

**(d)** Hum, don't see the point in the method, it should both print the value *and* return it.. well.. first off `public` lower case letters again,  `String` with a big letter (name of the class` and then the implementation:

```
public String printHouse(int area) {

    if (HouseMap.containsKey(area)) {
        String name = HouseMap.get(area);
        System.out.println("The house with the area code " + area + 
                           " is " + name));
        return name;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- a) only declare the variable - do not initialize it
- b) ok
- c) ok
- d) in a map you have random access. look at Map#get(Integer) [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29). you don't need to iterate over the entry set

Answer (score 1):

Since the key of a map is unique, you can simplify the last method as follows:

```
public static void printHouse( int area)
{
    String name = houseMap.get(area); // May return null
    System.out.println("House name is " + name);
    return name;
}
```

Comment: It should not print it if it wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

- `public` and `private` must be written with a lowercase p everywhere.
- You should show the entire constructor, not just the code that goes in it.
- Fix your indentation. Use the same amount of indentation for every level, and make sure that everything lines up neatly.
- When you use a foreach loop like `for (Integer eachcode: HouseMap.keySet())`, the iteration variable is `eachcode`. This is the value that you should compare to `area`, because that's what the integer is. You don't want to compare the supplied to all of the area codes taken as a single unit (those aren't the same kind of thing); you want to compare it to each area code in turn.
- But you don't want to write that loop at all. The point of a HashMap is to let you look up the value, given the key. That is what `.get()` does. You **have** the key: it is `area`. So all you need to do is look it up: `System.out.println("House name is " + HouseMap.get(area))`.
- You also need to return the name that you looked up, not just print it, and you need to check that the name is there (use `.contains()`) before printing.
- It looks like somebody else commented your code to say "you also forgot to return it". Did you try talking to this person, or reading the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint for the last one:

> (d) Write an **instance** method called

An instance method is not a **static** method, you have to remove the static keyword in your second (d) method...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for every body

> public static String printHouse(int
>   code) {
>
> ```
> if (houseMap.containsKey(code)) 
> { 
>     String name = houseMap.get(coe); 
>     System.out.println(code+  " : " + name); 
>     return name; 
> }   else{
>   System.out.println("null"); 
> return null; }
> ```